# cannot select profile for online event registration after upgrading civi on Joomla

Tags: civievent, joomla, upgrade

I've just upgraded CIVI on Joomla 3.4.1 from CiviCRM 4.5.3 to CiviCRM 4.6.9 and find that I can no longer select profiles to use for online event registrations when setting up an event.

I also find that when exporting participant records only the FIRST row of the exported csv file contains correct details for yes/no questions asked in existing custom data profiles. All following rows display numeric 1 or stay empty whereas first row correctly displays text "yes" or "no".

I could not replicate this issue on the demo joomla site, which is also Joomla 3.4.1 but running CiviCRM 4.6.0. I suspect the issue would appear on the demo site as well if it had a later version of civi.

I restored my website to pre-upgrade backup, then upgraded to CiviCRM 4.6.0. - This worked fine.

Then I did incremental upgrades of CIVI and all OK up to version 4.6.5 but when going from 4.6.5 to 4.6.6, the ability to select profiles and the odd behaviour with exporting participant data re-occurred.

I therefore suspect that code changes in civi 4.6.6 and onward cause this issue in Joomla installations.

I have found a similar issue that may or may not be relevant (but its too technical for me to be sure) https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15427

Is this a bug? if so how to progress it?

Comment: I asked a separate question about the state of joomla demo site at http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/why-is-joomla-demo-site-showing-it-is-using-4-6-0

Comment: it does sound like that same jira ticket, so it could be worth you reporting your findings there

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue where I could not select Profiles in Civi.  I am on a Wordpress site.  I found that Civi had a conflict with my theme (it was not a problem if I changed back to the default theme).  In my theme's functions.php file it had the following include which was causing the problem:

include_once('mkdinc/plugins/visual-composer.php');

I changed it to this:

if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'CiviCRM')
 ;//dont include it breaks civi
else
 include_once('mkdinc/plugins/visual-composer.php');

and the profiles were useable again.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Are you using a theme from Envato, say Salient?

Comment: I have used Salient for other sites but this one was Mikado1

Comment: Hrm ... That's what I was expecting.  Salient is still giving the same error with CiviCRM 4.7 on WP with PHP 5.4.  Now to find the equivalent call I guess.  Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Salient includes a customized Visual Composer.  Not seeing how to disable it as seen above.  Seems like it's chopping the page into thirds, and I'm not seeing how to disable it.  Either way, looks like a similar, but not exact issue.  Probably going to jump themes.

Comment: Just for search follow up information:  There seems to be a conflict between CiviCRM and the Salient theme on the loading of Backbone JQuery calls.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be very similar to [this other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/9635/44).  A client of ours encountered that exact issue: see [this answer to the other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/18137/44).

As it turns out, some of the problematic code was introduced to address CRM-15427, but some of it is separate.