# Why is Joomla demo site showing it is using 4.6.0?

Tags: joomla, demo-site

Following up on [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/cannot-select-profile-for-online-event-registration-after-upgrading-civi-on-joom) I checked and confirm that the joomla demo site shows it is on 4.6.0 and has 'security releases' available

Answer (score 4):

For background: The demo, training, test, and many local-dev systems for Drupal+CiviCRM and WordPress+CiviCRM are based on [a common set of scripts](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit), and they all install clean copies of Civi from git (using branches or version-tags). The demo sites are automatically rebuilt every night using the scripts. This keeps the sites up-to-date.

For Joomla: Installing a good, clean system for Joomla+CiviCRM from git is very difficult -- I and others have tried to automate it a few times and always given up. (Somewhere in my email history, there's a *note-to-self* about how hard this is. Alas, the language is too strong for publication.)

IMHO, there are two ways one can proceed with automating Joomla installation:

- Don't use git. Develop a different set of scripts based on zip files. (The [nightlies](http://dist.civicrm.org/by-date/latest/) might be good for this.)
- [Rewrite the installer](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35050.0.html)

At any rate... Without an automated installer, the Joomla demo site grows out-of-date periodically.