# Dropdowns Not Accessible

Tags: wordpress, option

[image]

Dropdowns are not accessible when clicked. Only when you close the window does the dropdown become accessible. After the window closes data does not save. Also getting duplicate action buttons on popup windows. I believe it is all related. Running Wordpress 4.7.3 and Civi 4.7.16. Same results on different computers and browsers.

[image]

Comment: It may be theme related similar to this post. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17761/online-registration-not-able-to-be-enabled. Can you witch to a different theme and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: we might need a tab for wordpress-theme since this seems to be a recurring issue

Comment: This is in the backend, so the odds of it being theme related were slim. I tried it with twenty twelve and one other and neither changed the outcome.

Comment: I have a similar issue with drop-downs and it is theme related. I'd try a newer theme than 2012. Go with twenty sixteen or seventeen. I just switch to twenty seventeen, select the drop-down and save then I switch back to my regular theme. I don't run into the problem very often so this is less work then rebuilding on a new theme.

Comment: You have this issue in the backend @CarlMiller?

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue. I downloaded and tried twenty seventeen, and did got the same issue. To verify it wasn't something wonky with cache I tried it in an incognito tab and had the same issue.

Comment: Do you have any CiviCRM custom CSS?

Comment: No :/ I try to keep it as clean as possible

Comment: Yes, when selecting drop-downs for Profile Options

Comment: Did you disable all non-civi plugins and try it?

Answer (score 3):

That's it @Carl Miller. I went through each plugin individually.

The [Slider Revolution](http://revolution.themepunch.com/) Plugin was doing it.